# connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL: role "rootuser" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, digital-ocean

I am trying to connect deploy a django backend with postgres db on digitalocean droplet. But it's giving me this error after after gunicorn and nginx setup:

```
connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "rootuser" does not exist`
```

"rootuser" is my root username not the db username, my db username is dbadmin

I tried to create db user with name serveroot, it worked but started throwing other errors:

```
relation "django_site" does not exist LINE 1: ..."django_site"."domain", "django_site"."name" FROM "django_si...
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the "root" user on Linux doesn't have direct access to PostgreSQL because it's a security risk. PostgreSQL is usually administered through the "postgres" system user or other dedicated roles with appropriate permissions.

1.Switch to the PostgreSQL User: On Ubuntu, PostgreSQL is often set up to use the "postgres" system user. You should switch to this user before running psql. You can do this with the su command:

```
sudo su - postgres
```

2.Run psql: Once you are the "postgres" user, you can run psql:

```
psql
```

[image: You can refer to my screenshot image..]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the docs about the settings file: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

Look for a section like this one:

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': YOUR_DB_NAME,
            'USER': USERNAME,
            'PASSWORD': PASSWORD_FOR_DB,
            'HOST': 'localhost'  // in Development.
        }
    }
```

and then change the `NAME`, `USER`, `PASSWORD` and `HOST` values to the ones you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i already did that

Comment: @AshutoshTripathi and what happened?